# Android: how to create a BitmapDrawable from a file in the file system?

Tags: java, android, bitmapdrawable

So I'm trying to restore an image from a file in my app's private files directory.

```
InputStream inputStream;
BitMapDrawable result;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        result = BitmapDrawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
        inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
return result;
```

But obviously I'm doing something wrong because result is always null.

Comment: What did LogCat show you? Have you tried `BitmapFactory`?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();`  never do this on android,  instead `Log.e("someStringValue", e.getMessage(), e);`   Then you will get propper logging in logcat and know what the error is.

Comment: Could you close this question by accepting an answer or adding one if the existing ones didn't solve this, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
new BitmapDrawable( BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()) );
```

Comment: This constructor was deprecated in API level 4.

Answer (score -1):

***Isn't It what you want?***

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Nope, I need to use the image as the background of a layout and it won't take a bitmap, only a drawable.